# is bean 'a' it still singleton spring?

Tags: spring, singleton

What happens in below example? Is class A is still a singleton object?

```
<bean id="a" class="A" singleton="true">  
   <property name="b">  
     <ref bean="b"/>  
   </property>  
</bean>  

<bean id="b" class="B" singleton="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is. The bean instance of a is a singleton object.
However take into consideration that bean b although it is not a singleton, the same b instance will be bound to the a singleton object.
In case of another singleton object that has a b instance this b instance shall be different.